# Cannot set background image in mPDF

Tags: mpdf

Cannot set background image on my mPDF document. It is always blank/white.
mpdf Version: dev-master@dev

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8', 
    'format' => [210, 100], 
    'orientation' => 'P',
]);
$stylesheet = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/certificate.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div class="content">Hello</div>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

certificate.css

```
@page {
  background-image: url("certificate-background.jpg");
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Please help.

**EDIT**

I worked around it with :

```
'watermarkImgBehind' => true
```

in $mpdf configuration and:

```
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage(__DIR__.'/certificate-background.jpg',1);
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
```

Comment: i had the same issue and narrowed it down to a self-signed certificate. in debug mode you may see something like _fopen failed to open stream..._ I fixed it by `@page {
  background-image: url("http://mydomain.fake/certificate-background.jpg");
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full mPDF package you'll find an example in php file named
example60_new_mPDF_v5-7_features.php
it contains a custom class

```
.divclip {
    border: 10px dashed #000000;
    border-radius: 3em;
    padding: 20px;
    background:yellow;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top right 210deg, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat ;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.divpic {
    background:yellow;
    background: yellow url("bayeux1.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Use this class for the table or div you want to set its background and it'll work, it worked for me.

e.g;

```
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" class="divclip divpic">
<tr>
<td  width="2%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

only need the follow code

```
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('img/marca_agua_ffyl.png', 1.0);   
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
```